# how to provide exclusive copies of big data repository to many developers?

Tags: bigdata, storage, cloud-storage

Here's a situation I am facing right now at work:

- we currently have 300GB+ of production data (and it increases every day at large). It's in a mongodb clustr
- data science team members are working on few algorithms that require access to all of this data at once and those algorithms may update data in place, hence, they have replicated the data in dev environment for their use until they are sure their code works
- if multiple devs are running their algorithms then all/some of them may end up with unexpected output because other algorithms are also updating the data
- this problem could be easily solved if everyone had their own copy of data!
- however, given the volume of data, it's not feasible for me to provide them (8 developers right now) with their exclusive copy everyday. Even if I automate this process, we'll have to wait until copy is completed over the wire
- I am hoping for a future proof approach considering we'll be dealing with TB's of data quite soon

I am assuming that many organizations would be facing such issues, and wondering how do other folks approach such a case.

I'd highly appreciate any pointers, leads, solutions for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using snapshots on the replicated data so each developer can have his own "copy" of the data. See [Snapshots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_(computer_storage)) definition and consult your cloud provider if it can provide writable snapshots.

Note, snapshots are created almost instantly and at the moment of creation they almost do not require storage space because this technology utilizes pointers but not data itself. Unfortunately each snapshot can grow up to the original volume size because any change of data will initiate physical data copy: the technology that hides behind the process is usually CoW - Copy-on-write. So there is a serious danger that uncontrolled snapshots can "eat" all your free storage space.